# Comparing a long std_logic_vector to zeros

Tags: vhdl

In simulation this works perfect. Is this is the best way of checking for
zeros for a synthesisable code. What would be the resources generated?

```
signal vector_slv : std_logic_vector(2048 downto 0);
...
if (vector_slv = (vector_slv'range => '0')) then
  -- do something...
```

Is there any other optimal way to implement this solution considering h/w mapping (with optimal resource utilization).

I would be more interested in understanding the resources used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way that makes more or less sense for synthesis. Write the code that best expresses your intention.

If you are comparing a vector for all zeros, the following should all produce the same results, or you should file a serious bug against the tool!

```
signal vector_slv : std_logic_vector(2048 downto 0);
constant zeros : std_logic_vector(vector_slv'range) := (others => '0');
...
if vector_slv = (vector_slv'range => '0') then
  -- do something...
if vector_slv = zeros then
  -- do something...
if unsigned(vector_slv) = to_unsigned(0, vector_slv'length) then
  -- do something...
```

and indeed for shorter vectors which fit in an integer:

```
if intvar = 0 then
```

will be exactly the same as any 32-bit vector comparison.

<sub>(BTW, note there is no need for parentheses around the `if` condition - VHDL is not C :)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

If the range is available, as in your example code, then the suggestion
solution looks fine, and I would expect that synthesis tools are made to handle
constructions like this.

If the range is not available, then compare with zero can be made like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
  if unsigned( {std_logic_vector expression of any length} ) = 0 then
    -- do something...
```

I would expect that synthesis tools handle this the same was as for compare
with `(vector_slv'range => '0')`.

Comment: When would the range not be available?

Answer (score 1):

As far as synthesis is concerned, yes, such simple constructs are usually optimized fairly well by the tool. The exact hardware layout of course depends on what your target is (FPGA, ASIC, ...).

My suggestion is to take a look at the synthesis result (e.g. Technology Map Viewer for Altera FPGAs). If synthesis clobbers it, you can manually convert it into a binary tree of comparisons with zero, taking into account the technology primitives you have available. This can be a lot more tricky than it sounds, though, especially for FPGAs (there's more than LUTs to play with there), and shouldn't be necessary with a decent tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also separate predicate and assignment by doing this :

```
signal is_zero : boolean;
signal vector_slv : std_logic_vector(2048 downto 0);
...
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    is_zero <= vector_slv = (vector_slv'range => '0');
    if is_zero then
      ...
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

This should improve your Timing very much. Take into account that the predicate 'is_zero' is now a delayed version of your original comparison !

Comment: Please explain why this should improve your timing very much.

Comment: Sure, if you don't split this predicate then you'll have a huge delay due to the predicate itself plus the delay of the assignments inside the 'if' block. If there is a multiply or add operation inside, this could easily exceed your clock period, especially when you'll have to use fast clocks.

Comment: … and especially when you're using very long vectors. If I would have to optimize code for your VERY long vectors, I would excessively split up all operations (predicates and math ops) into small pieces and use a kind of tree structure to enable parallelism instead of long chains. I don't know if Intel, Xilinx and Co. meanwhile have started to use this in their latest versions. The versions I had to do with were not optimized like that.

Comment: What's wrong with `if or vector_slv = '0' then` which also conveys you're looking for zero? You could also note signal `is_zero` won't be evlauated as zero until the next rising edge of `clk`. (There's an `is_zero` flip flop here whose output is evaluated on the clock edge.

Comment: @user1155120 : Comparison to zero and making an assignment in the same clock cycle is no problem if your clock is pretty slow, if your vectors are small and if your assignments are not demanding. If you're implementing things at the edge, you sometimes have to split up things to get it done inside the demanded clock cycle time. One means to do this is to split up predicate and assignment as a I have shown it further above. You are right, this would take two clock cycles instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the unary operators, e.g.:

- and
- nand
- or
- nor

```vhdl
signal vector_slv: std_logic_vector(2048 downto 0);
...
if and vector_slv then
    -- Do something for all 1...
elsif nand vector_slv then
    -- Do something for at least one 0...
elsif or vector_slv then
    -- Do something for at least one 1...
elsif nor vector_slv then
    -- Do something for all 0...
end if;
```

Or you could use the functions defined in [std_logic_1164](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/blob/master/libraries/ieee2008/std_logic_1164.vhdl), e.g.:

```vhdl
function "and"  (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
function "nand" (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
function "or"   (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
function "nor"  (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR) return STD_ULOGIC;
```

```vhdl
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
...
signal vector_slv: std_logic_vector(2048 downto 0);
...
if and(vector_slv) then
    -- Do something for all 1...
elsif nand(vector_slv) then
    -- Do something for at least one 0...
elsif or(vector_slv) then
    -- Do something for at least one 1...
elsif nor(vector_slv) then
    -- Do something for all 0...
end if;
```